# How to move files into the root of a zip archive?

Tags: python, zip, epub

So I finally figured out the main problem with my GenEpub.py program and why while it produces deflated, valid zip files as demonstrated by both `zip -t` and `zipinfo`, it fails the ultimate test of `epubcheck`.

The problem is as follows, the script below writes the whole folder called in this case `IdealogicalEcho`, then zips it up and names the zip file itself `IdealogicalEcho.epub`, as instructed. `epubcheck` however cannot see past this folder and then reports that none of the three core ePub files `mimetype META-INF OEBPS` can be found.

Is there a way of moving these files to the root of the zip directory? Either before or after zipping?

https://github.com/inferno986return/Damore-essay-ebook

Here's the current version of `EpubGen.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#GenEpub.py - Generates an .epub file from the data provided.
#Ideally with no errors or warnings from epubcheck (needs to be implemented, maybe with the Python wrapper).

import os
import json
import zipfile

with open('metadata.json') as json_file:
   data = json.load(json_file)

#The ePub standard requires deflated compression and a compression order.
zf = zipfile.ZipFile(data["fileName"] + '.epub', mode='w', compression=zipfile.ZIP_STORED)

zf.write(data["fileName"] + '/mimetype')

for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(data["fileName"] + '/META-INF'):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk(data["fileName"] + '/OEBPS'):
    zf.write(dirname)
    for filename in files:
        zf.write(os.path.join(dirname, filename))

zf.close()

#zipfile has a built-in validator for debugging
with open(data["fileName"] + '.epub','r') as f:
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(f) is True:
    print("ZIP file is valid.")

#Extra debugging information
#print(getinfo.compress_type(zf))
#print(getinfo.compress_size(zf))
#print(getinfo.file_size(zf))
```

And the `metadata.json`:

```
{
        "comment1": "Metadata.json - Insert the e-book's metadata here. WIP",

        "comment2": "Technical metadata - This is the where the cover image is specified. Recommended to use ePub V2.0.1 over 3.0 for epubVersion and Reflowable rather than Fixed for textPresentation (unless doing a project that requires a specific layout). mobiCover and generateKindle are currently unused but added for futureproofing.",
        "epubCover": "cover.jpg",
        "mobiCover": "cover.jpg",
        "fileName": "IdealogicalEcho",
        "epubVersion": "2.0.1",
        "textPresentation": "Reflowable",
        "generateKindle": "no",

        "comment3": "Book metadata - Information about the e-book itself. Language is specified with ISO 639-1. Rights can be worldwide, country specific or under a permissable license such as Creative-Commons SA",
        "title": "Google's Idealogical Echochamber: How bias clouds our thinking about diversity and inclusion",
        "creator": "James Damore",
        "subject": "Academic",
        "publisher": "Hal Motley",
        "ISBN": "-",
        "language": "en",
        "rights": "Creative Commons BY-SA 4.0",

        "comment4": "This is the page order that the e-book has. The first number before the colon is the page order, the second is the indentation, third is the page name and fourth is file itself.",
        "pages": [
                {
                    "pageNumber": "0",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Cover",
                    "fileName": "bookcover.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "1",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Title",
                    "fileName": "title.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "2",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Indicia",
                    "fileName": "indicia.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "3",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "License",
                    "fileName": "license.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "4",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Contents",
                    "fileName": "toc.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "5",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Foreword",
                    "fileName": "foreword.xhtml"
                },
                {
                    "pageNumber": "6",
                    "indentation": "0",
                    "pageName": "Article",
                    "fileName": "article.xhtml"
                }
            ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> z = ZipFile('test', 'w')
>>> help(z.write)
Help on method write in module zipfile:

write(self, filename, arcname=None, compress_type=None) method of zipfile.ZipFile instance
    Put the bytes from filename into the archive under the name
    arcname.
```

There's a second argument to `.write` for zip files that indicates the name of where to store the file within the zip.  So, for your example, `zf.write(data["fileName"] + '/mimetype', 'mimetype')` ought to do the trick.

Comment: It indeed works nicely for <code>mimetype</code> and I feel like I am a third of the way to solving this problem. I am stumped on the two directories <code>META-INF</code> and <code>OEBPS</code>.